# How to set default kernel in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub2, grub

I am having  a `5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64` kernel and have installed `5.10.0-12-amd64` kernel on Debian `11.2`. I want to set  `5.10.0-12-amd64` as the default kernel temporarily.I am new to Grub, How to set the default kernel as `5.10.0-12-amd64`?
My `/lib/modules`:

```
5.10.0-10-cloud-amd64  5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64  5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64
5.10.0-11-amd64        5.10.0-12-amd64
```

My /boot/ only has grub folder and no grub2 folder.
Command `grep -e "menuentry " -e submenu -e linux /boot/grub/grub.cfg` yields :

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0 
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0 
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64-recovery-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0 
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-recovery-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0 
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64-recovery-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-11-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-11-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0 
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-11-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-11-amd64-recovery-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 consoleblank=0
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
```

Thanks telcoM for providing the above command

Comment: see here @HeinrichReinhardArbeit https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, check `/etc/default/grub`. There should be a `GRUB_DEFAULT=` variable in it. If it is set to `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` or unset, the default will be to boot the first entry in the boot menu (entry #0). If it is set to **anything other than** `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`, the only way to reliably change the default will be to edit `GRUB_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub` (or `grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) as root.

If the setting **is** `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`, then two commands, `grub-reboot` and `grub-set-default` will be usable. The former will set the kernel to boot *for one boot only* and then will return to the previous default. The latter will switch the GRUB default entry until you change it again, either by using `grub-set-default` or by selecting something else in the GRUB boot menu.

The simplest form of default setting specifies just the menu entry number (starting from entry #0 at the top). But modern GRUB menu is usually constructed to have the newest kernel in the first position, then *a submenu of all the other kernels* in the second position, and any other OSs and other custom entries after that submenu.

To view the GRUB menu in useful way, run `grep -e "menuentry " -e submenu -e linux /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. (The space after `menuentry` is needed to filter out some false hits.) You will see a number of fairly long `menuentry` and `submenu` lines, *in the exact same order the real menu will have*. Also, the entries of the submenu will be indented, while the main menu entries won't be. This will allow you to see the structure of the currently active GRUB menu without rebooting the system.

The title of the topmost menu item is usually unhelpfully just "Debian GNU/Linux" with no kernel version number, but the command I gave above will also list the `linux /boot/vmlinuz-<kernel version number> ...` command that is part of the first menu entry block, and that will reveal the exact kernel version that will be booted by the topmost entry.

If you need to select a menu entry that is within the submenu (i.e. its `menuentry` line is indented), then the default entry specification should be the identifier of the `submenu` line, a `>` character, and then the identifier of the actual menu entry you want. The menu entry identifiers can be menu entry numbers (starting from 0 in each menu), identifier strings (the quoted strings after the `$menuentry_id_option` on each `menuentry` or `submenu` line), or the visible titles of each menu item and submenu.

The identifier strings for Linux kernels seem to be of the form `gnulinux-simple-<Linux root filesystem UUID>` for the first entry, and `gnulinux-<kernel version>-advanced-<Linux root filesystem UUID>` for the entries in the "Advanced options ..." submenu.

The visible menu item titles in US English-configured Debian 11 are "Debian GNU/Linux" for the first item, "Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux" for the submenu, and "Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux " for the non-recovery-mode entries in the submenu.

So, assuming your GRUB menu has no other OSs complicating the matters, you could set the `5.10.0-12-amd64` kernel as the default until you change it back by editing the `GRUB_DEFAULT=` line in your `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64"
```

and running `update-grub` as root.

If you want more flexibility, you might instead set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`, run `update-grub`, and then run `grub-set-default "1>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64"` to change the default until you change it back, or run `grub-reboot "1>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64"` to change the default for one boot only.

The `1>` prefix comes from the requirement to first select the submenu entry, and the fact that it's always the second entry in the main GRUB menu (i.e. menu item #1).

If you used `grub-set-default`, you can return to whatever kernel is currently the "latest" according to simple alpha-numeric sorting, by using `grub-set-default 0`.

Remember, the first entry in each menu level is numbered #0. With your menu entries, you could specify the `menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64'` line with menu entry numbers as:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

i.e. the second entry (entry #1) opens the submenu, and then pick the third entry (entry #2) of the submenu.

Or with menu titles as:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64"
```

Or with menu ID strings as:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d>gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d"
```

Or with any combination of the above methods.

The advantage of using the menu titles or ID strings is that they keep referring to the same kernel even if you install & remove kernel packages, as long as the chosen kernel is still available. Using the menu item numbers would require you to check (and adjust if necessary) the settings after each kernel update, so if used together with any kind of automatic updates, it might cause nasty surprises.

Comment: It might be worth to note that "saved" will silently fail when lvm is used, as grub refuses to write to lvm-managed partitions.

Comment: Good point. GRUB's write support is very very simple: basically it relies on a `/boot/grub/grubenv` file already existing with enough space allocated to it, so GRUB will just change existing file contents without changing the total length of the file, so it won't have to make any changes to the filesystem metadata. For this reason, on anything that is more complex than a plain filesystem (i.e. LVM or software RAID) GRUB might refuse writing altogether, out of abundance of caution.

Comment: Does the menu entry identifier start with 0 as topmost entry or the first sub menu entry?

Comment: `0` would be the topmost entry of the main menu. If the second entry at the main menu is a submenu, the first entry of the submenu would be `1>0`. But the documentation recommends using menu identifier strings or menu titles instead of the numbers, for whatever reason.

Comment: I have pasted the output of your command in the question and I am going to use ```GRUB_DEFAULT='3>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64'```for the third indented submenu entry i.e.  ```menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d' {```Please can you verify it??

Comment: So the second entry in the main menu and third from the submenu? That would be `1>2` in the shortest possible form, or `1>gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d` using the menu entry ID of the submenu entry only, or `gnulinux-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d>gnulinux-5.10.0-12-amd64-advanced-ccb4ba21-fd62-42c9-b8eb-75a437b1747d` using entry IDs for both the main menu and submenu choices. If you use the title of the submenu entry, then `1>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-12-amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud images are built without support for features that are unnecessary in cloud environments.

Most hardware drivers are disabled, x32 ABI support is disabled, as are microcode updates and machine check exceptions.

The kernel that you choose will depend on the utility that you will give to the instance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417104)